# What is a non-hazardous method to remove the letters from keyboard keys without introducing a non-smooth texture?

Tags: keyboard

I need to remove the letters and numbers from the keys on a number of keyboards. This needs to be done in a non-hazardous fashion without introduction extra physical textures on the keys.

The keys are standard plastic keys on Microsoft keyboards.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by non-hazardous?

Comment: I can't use any chemicals that will cause health problems or finger irritation after letter/number removal

Comment: You're probably just going to have to experiment with a number of solvents until you find one that works. Once the job is done, a wash in soapy water should remove the solvent. I would try things like Goo Gone, fingernail polish remover (both with and without acetone), lighter fluid and WD-40. Plan on sacrificing several key caps to the  point of needing replacement until you find a solution (no pun intended). I have to say, this is a very unusual request.

Comment: @Dennis, I've seen this done for touch-typing tests. That's about the only situation I've seen where this would be desirable though apart from being incredibly leet (referring to your answer below).. sorry l33t...

Comment: @Farseeker: n00b! That's "l337". ;-) If you want *real* l337 and have the US$1600 or so to spare, the Optimus Maximus is the must-have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: das keyboard ultimate]
<sub>(source: [daskeyboard.com](http://www.daskeyboard.com/images/products/ultimate/2.jpg))</sub>

Das Keyboard Ultimate - no key inscriptions

Comment: Warning: $129 may be hazardous.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.fentek-ind.com/kbblnk.htm) also sells blank keyboards (and in 90's web style!) for ~$50.  They also sell blank key overlays, so maybe you could just cover over the keys instead of removing the ink?